# Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. Should I re-install Gem or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deprecated

I'm learning RoR on Ubuntu 11. Got the following message when I was trying to generate an app. Did I install something incorrectly?

```
$ rails generate controller Pages home contact
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:162.
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:84.
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem????

Answer (score 53):

This worked for me: downgrade rubygems:

```
gem update --system 1.6.2
```

found this advice at: [Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification #34](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/issues/34)

Comment: Worked well for me, all other suggestions failed :/

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04 running a chiliproject (redmine) ruby app. `gem update bundler` failed to eliminate the error/warning

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
sudo gem update bundler
```

This will update bundler to most recent version (currently 1.0.15). This will not generate the warning or at least in my case this was the cause of the warning.

Comment: Hi dexter, I have the same problem that this post are complaining and I ran this update command and "Nothing to update" was outputted. And the error persist, do you have any other tip? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey @Castanho try running just gem update bundler (without the sudo).

Comment: yupp... `gem update bundler` (without sudo) worked for me. Thanks @KevinTsoi

Answer (score 14):

The best way to solve this is:

```
$ gem pristine --all --no-extensions
```

This will rebuild all gems (excluding those with native extensions) and update their gemspecs. If you don't have any gems with native extensions or you didn't use any custom compile flags on those gems you can also omit the `--no-extensions` flag. Otherwise you'll have to build them seperately.

Comment: Thank you Koraktor for the input :)

Comment: I tried the command (with "--no-extensions" and without "--no-extensions", but I still get the same error message. Thank you for showing that you cared by responded to the question. I went on trying more stuff after seeing your post and I was able to stumble upon a solution :)

Comment: @Kevin H, so what was the solution you stumbled upon?

Comment: I wrote recorded the 'partial solution' below, which was typing "sudo gem update". When I type 'rails generate controller ...", I don't see the message any more =). However, when I ran "autotest", the message shows up. So, it was not a full solution. Sorry for the trouble :). I will keep trying and provide updates.

Comment: worked well when I used
`sudo gem pristine --all --no-extensions`
on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

I tried "sudo gem update".
After that, I don't see the message "Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification..." anymore. Yay!

Comment: Note on 2011-05-25: I still see ""Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification..." when I ran "autotest". Looks like the problem is not solved yet. I will reinstall Ruby + Rails.

Answer (score -1):

rails -v = 2.2.2

ruby -v = 1.8.7

[This link helps me.](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/issues/34)

or simply do

```
gem update --system 1.6.2
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7536173/7852