# ROR deprecation warning desert-0.5.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warnings, deprecated

So I am getting this error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths is deprecated, 
please use autoload_paths instead. (called from load_paths at 
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/desert-0.5.4/lib/desert/manager.rb:36)
```

times like a million
after call ruby script/server
before this warning

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.12 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

and then after the activesupport error I get a bunch of

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.12/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:78.
```

and then after all these warnings and notes I get

```
/Users/anthonysierra/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4/lib/bcrypt_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [x86_64-darwin10]

Abort trap
```

My questions is how I might add gems or install things in order to get things running? In case you are wondering this is a project I pulled from svn.

Answer (score 1):

The deprecation warnings have been added to `ActiveSupport` in version 2.3.9 (source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.9/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb)). They're just that, warnings.

For the `Gem.source_index` note, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065383/gem-source-index-is-deprecated-use-specification-should-i-re-install-gem-or-rai).

The `bcrypt` error should be solved by reinstalling `bcrypt` (see related bug [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/415)).

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like what I had to do was add 
gem 'bcyrpt-ruby', :require => "crypt" to the gemfile and then call sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution here. As a bonus: You might want to look into using [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/). This way you don't have to install your gems using `sudo` and you can run multiple versions of Ruby side-by-side. You can also create different 'gemsets' to avoid conflicts.