# Error when following tutorial on Rails in Aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana3

I'm new to Ruby and Rails. I'm trying to follow a [getting started tutorial](http://www.tuanleaded.com/blog/2012/04/getting-started-with-ruby-on-rails/) and get the following error at "Launching Your First Rails app".

```
 NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /media/05641c6e-483c-49ea-ad48-a68f63984bf1/ruby/workspace/Test/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /media/05641c6e-483c-49ea-ad48-a68f63984bf1/ruby/workspace/Test/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:100.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- rack/handler/--binding=0.0.0.0 (MissingSourceFile)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler.rb:63:in `try_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
    from /media/05641c6e-483c-49ea-ad48-a68f63984bf1/ruby/workspace/Test/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:45
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /media/05641c6e-483c-49ea-ad48-a68f63984bf1/ruby/workspace/Test/script/server:3
```

Any help on how to solve this problem is much appreciated. Also, if someone can explain how to understand the issue using the stacktrace, it will be very helpful.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but if you are just starting would it not be better to start with the latest version of Ruby (2.x) and Rails (4.x)? You appear to use Ruby 1.8 still. Instructions for downloading and installing the most recent versions are here: http://rubyonrails.org/download

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065383/gem-source-index-is-deprecated-use-specification-should-i-re-install-gem-or-ra

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I have installed the versions that are installed from apt rather than manually installing the latest version.